# Why my output gives some garbage values, even though I input them

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list, nested, queue

I was making my high school project and decided to use something like nested linked lists for some bonus marks. The aim of my project was to create a digital diary containing infinite no of pages and infinite no of lines per page. My program uses a linked list as a queue and each element in the queue has its own linked list as a queue. I am using arrays for headings and for each sub unit (line) of the nested queue and the gets and puts for input/output. My program displays the input data but not all correctly, the last elements of the array are sometimes smileys and arrows instead of what I put.I am using a structure for line, a class to use that queue and a derived class for the page which contains the heading, page no and the class containing lines. The derived class objects are now used as the bigger linked list in another class. Also, I wish to save the data to a binary file, please tell me whether should I store it as line by line or page by page. I am using C++

Comment: What programming language are you using? Any code you can share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that comes to my mind is error in pointer dereferencing. Basically, your linked lists are pulling data from the wrong sector in memory. Try going through it again and see whether everything is referenced properly and data input is going where it must. Trying saving the data line by line to avoid again overflows or errors. If successful then try page by page.